# How to Retrieve value from a UDT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Goal:
I want to reach and display the value of @data inside if [wwtest].

Problem:
The UDT is from the database [test] and I retrieve an error message "The type name 'test.dbo.tvf_id' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 1.".

I don't know how to retrieve the data from the database test inside of the query document for [wwtest]?

[image]

The Sourcecode below is created inside of the database test.

```
create table datatable (id int,
                        name varchar(100),
                        email varchar(10),
                        phone varchar(10),
                        cellphone varchar(10),
                        none varchar(10)                        
                       );

insert into datatable values
  (1, 'productname', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
  (2, 'cost', '20', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  (3, 'active', 'Y', 'A', 'A', 'A');

insert into datatable values
  (4, 'productname', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
  (5, 'cost', '20', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  (6, 'active', 'Y', 'A', 'A', 'A');


insert into datatable values
  (7, 'productname', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
  (8, 'cost', '20', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  (9, 'active', 'Y', 'A', 'A', 'A');




CREATE TYPE [tvf_id] AS TABLE
(
    [id] [int] NULL
    ,[OrdCol] [INT] NOT NULL    
)
GO



DECLARE @data tvf_id INSERT INTO @data([id],[OrdCol]) 
VALUES (8,1), (2,2), (4,3), (1,4), (3,5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. A table type just can be used inside it's database. You try to access it like that: `[test].[dbo].[tvf_id]`

Instead try this: `[dbo].[tvf_id]`

As your error already stated, you exceed the maximum of allowed prefixes. 1 is allowed (dbo) and you use two (test + dbo).

For further information read [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178069(v=sql.105).aspx). As it seems that you try to use a table type outside of it's database.

Only way to solve this may be to move your logic to the other database and just push the data later on to wwtest. Another idea could be to create the same table type in wwtest too.

Comment: If I use "[dbo].[tvf_id]", I retrieve the message "Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type dbo.tvf_id." because it try looking it inside of the database wwtest. The dbo.tvf_id is located in the database test.

Comment: I also have removed and display "[dbo]" once in the doucment but the same message is still the same.

Comment: Well, as I already said in my answer. You can use a table type only in it's defined database table.

Comment: If you need, you can move your logic to the other database. Another idea is to copy the table type definition to your wwtest. Or you can run it inside an dynamic sql statement (which won't be too good i think)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a table variable, you don't use three part naming:

```
declare @data table (id int, ordcol int);

insert into @data(id, ordcol)
    values (. . .);
```

Three (or four) part naming applies to actual tables, not to temporary tables or table variables.